# What do we mean by philosophy of physics or math what does it tell us about them?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics

what do we mean by philosophy of physics or math what does it tell us about them ?
Does it tell about how these disciplines of knowledge develop?
For example to develop math we use axiomatic approach and for physics we use scientific method.

Comment: I'd say that philosophy-of-x tends to be to steering the wheel, digesting the foundations of the science and pushing the boundaries while trying to understand which topics should be more relevant and researched.

Answer (score 3):

The axiomatic method is what people think of when they hear the term philosophy of mathematics. It's an important idea nevertheless it's not the only idea in the philosophy of mathematics, and because of this - it's over-rated; for example, cohomology is an important notion in mathematics; and it has an axiomatic formulation, but this tells you very little about what cohomology is, and why it's important; its use-value, that is as used by mathematicians in the world of mathematics gives a much better indication of what it is; use gives ontology here. Robert Langlands, who is famous for the Langlands programme, said:

> Our difficulty is not the proofs, but learning what to prove

In fact, a major part of his work is reformulating non-abelian class field theory, an important part of number theory; it's usually called the Langlands programme but I have also heard it referred to as the Langlands philosophy.

I also think its a mistake to think that the philosophy of mathematics, physics and science more broadly must only reflect on the problems of these subjects, or their inter-relationships or their foundations; these subjects are embedded in society, and an important part of philosophy is to investigate the relationship of these subjects to the larger society.

For example the notion of algorithm is a mathematical concept and today we have such things as algorithmic trading, predictive policing and other ways in which the use of algorithms affect the wider society. The recent scandal with Cambridge Analytica highlights some of the dilemmas that a philosophy of algorithms might help frame.

Comment: So you are saying that discovering the development process of these disciplines of knowledge is one of the area of their philosophy but not the only one there are many other things when we say their philosophy.

Comment: And when you say that when we think of philosophy of math axiomatic system comes to mind. The scientific method is equivalent to axiomatic system in physics which has its own philosophy what does that tell us about the scientific method.

Comment: @remy: yes to your first comment; but no to your second - the scientific method is *not* equivalent to the axiomatic method.

Comment: By saying equivalent i meant to be their role in those disciplines that is to develop not that they are same process

Comment: @remy: ok, thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Philosophy of science is completely superfluous for the working physicist - according to Feynman's ironic statement

*The philosophy of science is as useful to scientists as ornithology is to birds.*

To explain why muons reach the earth before decaying, you need some knowledge about time dilation from the Special Theory of Relativity. And to prove that a^n+b^n=c^n, n > 2, has no non-trivial solution, you must understand the sophisticated mathematics of Wiles proof of the Shimura-Taniyama-Weil conjecture. In both cases, philosophy of physics and philosophy of mathematics did not contribute any piece of insight to the answer.

Nevertheless, in mathematics there are certain foundational questions around set theory and some philosophizing along the lines "Which ontological state do mathematical objects have?" But these questions do not find a generally accepted answer. In addition, most working mathematicians care about such issues at most on Sunday morning, when other work is done.

Possibly this answer sounds a bit harsh. Please note: I do not deny that one can find philosophy of science an interesting subject. And that this type of philosophy can be a satisfying occupation. My point is to stress the irrelevance of this field to the working scientist as Feynman stated above.

Comment: It's muons not myons. You don't need philosophy to to spell correctly either.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the "muons". I apologize, being not a native speaker I used the German term.

Comment: Your summary seems correct to me. Philosophy is a global study and once it is called 'philosophy of something or other' it ceases to be itself. Philosophy cannot be solved or understood piecemeal.

Comment: Quoting Feynman is generally not very illuminating. He said the most ridiculous stuff – hiding behind irony. For Feynman, taking him at face value, most mathematics is also useless. And interestingly Wiles' original proof uses an additional axiom beyond those of ordinary set theory, which seems pretty relevant to the discussion.

Comment: 1) Could you please give a reference for your statement "For Feynman, taking him at face value, most mathematics is also useless." 2) Which additional axiom from set theory did Wiles use in his proof?

Comment: 1.) “If all mathematics disappeared, it would set physics back precisely one week.” / “Physics is to mathematics what sex is to masturbation.” (in P. H. Nahin: “Number-Crunching” /  L. M. Krauss: “Fear of Physics: A Guide for the Perplexed”) 2.) “To complete his proof, Wiles assumed the existence of a type of large cardinal known as an inaccessible cardinal, technically overstepping the bounds of conventional arithmetic.” (Richard Elwes: “To infinity and beyond: The struggle to save arithmetic” in *New Scientist, 2010*)

Comment: There is an interesting discussion of the experts about whether it is necessary to introduce inaccesible cardinals for Wiles proof, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35746/inaccessible-cardinals-and-andrew-wiless-proof

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats: I don't think we should Feynman at face value; if all of mathematics disappeared, it would take a great deal of work to get it back, and to get physics as it is now; I read him as saying that mathematics as a discipline is different from physics - and one shouldn't confuse the two. At the time he was around, mid 20th C, mathematics had gone its own way with its own problems. For example, Feynman tried learning some homotopy theory. At that time there were no applications of this theory in physics. This isn't true now. For example, in the theory instantons.

Comment: Also, going on from the discussion in MO, it's the use of cohomology of sheaves that is important in Wiles work, not inaccessible cardinals per se; the set theoretic foundations of this theory require large sets, much larger than classical ZFC.

Comment: @JoWehler is completely clueless. Special relativity and general relativity are two theories that were motivated by deep philosophical insights. Einstein himself acknowledged it and emphasized the importance of philosophy of physics in foundational work.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I'm just on a mission to get people stop quoting Feynman. Because he said too much ridiculous and indeed obnoxious stuff – hiding behind joking and irony. What he *really* thought is just speculation and that's why you should not quote Feynman.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats: What is wrong with a sense of humour? Please don't tell me what I can or cannot say - are you sure you don't have authoritarian tendencies? I would agree that Feynman is perhaps quoted too often, but then he is a famous figure and deservedly so, but people should read around. There's plenty of things that other scientists have said that deserves a hearing.

Comment: @sure I am bit doubtful about the impact of philosophy on Einstein's theoretical physics. There is some influence from Mach concerning the impact of stars far away. But the fundamental idea to encorporate gravity into geometry is not due to Mach. Which remark of Einstein do you have in mind?

Comment: *“The female mind is capable of understanding analytic geometry. Those people who have for years been insisting (in the face of all obvious evidence to the contrary) that the male and female are equally capable of rational thought may have something. The difficulty may just be that we have never yet discovered a way to communicate with the female mind. If it is done in the right way, you may be able to get something out of it.”* – Richard Feynman.

Comment: @MoziburUllah  Feynman's “jokes” lack a punchline. It's always just ironic exaggeration for the sake of offending people. That's it. Because of this, the problem with quoting him is that it's a mystery how much of his exaggerations he really believed himself.

Comment: @wolf-revo-cats: Most women I've met aren't interested in the finer points of geometry, and I think that is what Feynman is trying to get at; this does not mean some aren't - for example Emmy Noether; egalitarianism does not mean equality in aptitudes, but equality of opportunity; not all humour requires a punch-line. Trying reading Henry James *The Bostonians*, the first few pages are a comic master-piece and there isn't a punch line in sight.

Comment: @JoWehler https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_physics#Quotes_from_Einstein's_work_on_the_importance_of_the_philosophy_of_physics 

You don't need this quote in any case, if you *understood* special relativity and general relativity, or the contribution of Einstein to the foundation of QM.